Using Kendo-Timepicker i need to display the time list in 30 minutes difference, like customise the time list selection. How to do that?
[enter image description here] (https://i.sstatic.net/U0UN6HED.png)
LIke this , in this kendo-time picker
Using Kendo-Timepicker i need to display the time list in 30 minutes difference, like customise the time list selection. How to do that?
I could not able to display the customize times, how do that one.
